# Romulans want their cloaking tech back for maintenance - invisible Articles show up on the radar

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives, articles

Using the search operator `is:article` yields a result set of 18 Articles (as expected), however, the total shows "23 results". This does not seem to be correct — even the Stack Exchange API returns only 18 items from the [`/articles`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/articles#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!-)8(vv2cdSXI&site=stackoverflow&run=true) endpoint.

[image: search results screenshot saying there are 23 results]

If the search returns deleted articles for members of a Collective (I am a member of the Google Cloud one), they should be in the result set.

If it should not return them, they should not count towards the total.

If those are Articles pending approval, they should not be counted towards the total either.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! This is indeed a bug, we'll fix it (and post an answer when it's done). I'll mark it as `[status-planned]` in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, @JD-Stack! Initial credit for finding out about the bug goes to [KevinB](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54732059#54732059), though :)